# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'. > Please fix the version conflict either by

Tags: android, manifest

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.0.4.

What to fix in manifest or build.gradle or ??

I am using Android Studio 3.1 Canary 5
    Build #AI-171.4474551, built on November 30, 2017
    JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01 amd64
    JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
    Windows 7 6.1

### my build.gradle file looks like below

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

     android {
        compileSdkVersion 24
        buildToolsVersion '27.0.1'

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "in.easym2m.easyui"
            minSdkVersion 20
            targetSdkVersion 24
            compileOptions {
                sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
                targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            }
        }

        buildTypes {
            debug {
                minifyEnabled true
                useProguard false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
            release {
                shrinkResources true
                minifyEnabled true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                //minifyEnabled false
                //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        //classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2' // google-services plugin
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.1'

        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4' //Maps
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.2'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.2'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.6.2'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.2'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.2'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.6.2'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:11.6.2'
        compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:18.0.0'
        compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
        compile files('libs/acra-4.7.0.jar')
        compile files('libs/activation.jar')
        compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
        compile files('libs/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar')
        compile files('libs/commons-configuration-1.10.jar')
        compile files('libs/commons-lang-2.6.jar')
        compile files('libs/eventbus-2.4.0.jar')
        compile files('libs/mail.jar')
        compile files('libs/httpcore_4.2.3.jar')
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the
>   google-services plugin (information about the latest version is
>   available at
>   https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/)
>   or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.0.4.

You should use **`SAME`** version

> Note: Don't use the combined play-services target. It brings in dozens
>   of libraries, bloating your application. Instead, specify only the
>   specific Google Play services APIs your app uses.

**Don't**

```
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4' 
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.2'
```

**Do**

```
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0' 
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
  compile 'com.google.......................:11.8.0'
```

Read [**`Set Up Google Play Services`**](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup).

Comment: After that, `Clean-Rebuild-Run`. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Change the versions of these two dependencies (in your project they are 11.0.4):

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.2' //Maps
```

All your dependencies from same host (in your case from google) should have matching versions. *Also you can use the latest version 11.8.0, but make sure to set it to all your google dependencies.*

Answer (score 0):

Both `firebase` version and `google` version should be same

```
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0' //Maps
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:11.8.0'
```

Refer https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me for Android studo 3.1 Canary version

in project (not module) build.gradle

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0-alpha05'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2' // google-services plugin
    }
```

and I manually put google-services.json in app/src folder in file explorer of windows 8

DONT: copy google-services.json on app dir of Android studio.

Comment: Glad to see, You solved. But you should use SAME version as well.